# Что такое smoke test и с чем его едят?

Tags: linux, shell, freebsd, test-automation

Что такое smoke test? Гугл дал только краткую формулировку, а хотелось бы с конкретными примерами, литературой и т. д. Как можно запустить данные тесты ( какие команды в shell'е ) в разных unix подобных ос для разных утилит. Насколько я понимаю, для каждой программы есть определенный набор команд ( tool -h или -version ), и проверив работоспособность такого manpage можно сказать, что данная утилита прошла smoke test или нет.

Comment: С чем его "курят" :D

Answer (score 1):

> какие команды в shell'е

Проще всего:

```
if tool -h
then
   echo "Прошли smoke test"
else
   echo "Не прошли smoke test"

if tool --version
then
   echo "Прошли smoke test"
else
   echo "Не прошли smoke test"
```

Но не факт, что все разработчики tool достаточно добросовестны и снабдили свой tool обработкой этих опций.

Answer (score 1):

Только проверку того, что тулза скомпилировалась - сложно назвать smoke-test.

- **Smoke-test** должен поверхностно протестировать наличие и корректную работу в тривиальных случаях всех самых важных функций тестируемой системы.
- **Основная задача** - охватить как можно больше функциональности за кратчайшее время. Никаких сложных кейсов.
- **Цель** - выявление проблем со сборкой перед её скармливанием более глубоким методам тестирования, экономия времени, очистка истории сборок от случайных ошибок.

Дымовое тестирование имеет смысл размещать не на серверах CI, а у конкретных разработчиков либо на хуки системы контроля версий на development сервере.

Его, в принципе, можно не автоматизировать(хотя тогда есть риск его пропустить). Разработчик может просто самостоятельно пробежаться по всем(не только по тем, в которые он вносил изменения) важным узлам билда вручную - это тоже вполне себе `smoke-тестирование`

---

По поводу утилит, вы используете привычные вам методы тестирования, различие только в наборе тестов - вы идёте не в глубину, а в ширину.

Answer (score 1):

Само выражение *smoke test* - пришло из электроники. Собрали вы новое устройство, включили его в розетку, а оно громко бабахнуло и выпустило *белый дым* - значит *smoke test* не пройден.

В программировании *smoke test* обозначает достаточно быстрый тест самой важной функциональности. Какой именно, зависит от программы.

Например для интернет браузера будет достаточно открыть какой-нибудь https://google.com